# While processing template api/[TodoController], a replacement value for the token TodoController could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to this and following this [.Net ASP.NET wep api tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) but cant get past this error. When doing the "Test the GetTodoItems method" and running the Postman to get/set against the DB.

When I start debugging, Chrome launches and the following error is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The following errors occurred with
>   attribute routing information:
>
> Error 1: For action: 'TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetTodoItems
>   (TodoApi)' Error: While processing template 'api/[TodoController]', a
>   replacement value for the token 'TodoController' could not be found.
>   Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a
>   literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]'
>   instead.
>
> Error 2: For action: 'TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetTodoItem
>   (TodoApi)' Error: While processing template
>   'api/[TodoController]/{id}', a replacement value for the token
>   'TodoController' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action,
>   controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or
>   within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.'

This is my controller code straight from the tutorial:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[TodoController]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                // Create a new TodoItem if collection is empty,
                // which means you can't delete all TodoItems.
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        // GET: api/Todo
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Todo/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
        {
            var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (todoItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return todoItem;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the 
        //container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP 
        //request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for 
                // production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you encountered like share it.

Comment: By the way, that tutorial **does not** have that code. When a tutorial/book you are following doesn't seem to work, you should double check your code actually matches.

Comment: Well as the picture(that perfectly show where, what) happens is now gone so the error is at line 46 in the startup.cs, as `app.UseMvc(); `

Comment: @ExocetKid No, that line only ensures what you configured is correct, and, as the exception told you, there was something incorrect. That line did not have any problem of its own

Comment: @ExocetKid the error happens there because that is when it is generating all the routes and adding them to the route table..

Comment: You misunderstood the statement in the tutorial. It says 
`Replace [controller] with the name of the controller`
Meaning you need to take the whole `[controller]` and replace it with the name of the controller which is `Todo`. So the result will be just `[Route("api/Todo")]`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the problem relates to building the routes for your TodoController. The key part of the message is this:

> a replacement value for the **token** 'TodoController' could not be found

`[controller]` in the route template is a token which ASP.NET Core will automatically replace when adding the route to the route table.

For example, given your controller is called `TodoController`, the your route should be `api/[controller]`,

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase {
    //...
}
```

then the final route will be `api/Todo`.

As noted by the exception, using the literal `[TodoController]` isn't a known ASP.NET Core routing token. Which will cause the error when the framework tries to generate the attribute routes.

See [Token replacement in route templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error until changed

```
[Route("api/[message]")]
```

On

```
[Route("api/message")]
```

Comment: Did you change it _from_ the former _to_ the latter? Or vice versa? I wasn't clear what you meant by "on" here. In context, I assume the format, but didn't want to change it to "to" without first confirming.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Its supposed to be the latest one. Like this: [Route("api/message")]

Answer (score 1):

I have changed from [Route("api/[TodoItemsController]")] to [Route("api/TodoItemsController")]. It worked. Yay